# How to filter requests in Sinon

Tags: javascript, jasmine, sinon

I am writing unit tests in Jasmine for Backbone application. And of course I use Sinon in my tests. But now I have problem. I am writing tests for Login screen and I need simulate server responce - because server works very bad. Now my code looks:

```
describe('Login', function(){
     it('Should simulate server response', function(){
        server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
        server.respondWith("GET", "http:\\example.com", [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, '{"Body:""asd"}'])
     })
     $('body').find('button#login').trigger('click');
     server.respond();
     server.restore()
     console.log(server.requests);
})
```

And this code works fine, but I see in console that fakes all requests, but during Login I also have other requests, and I don't need use fake server for them. It is requests for next screen. Maybe exist way to make filter or use fake responds for special requests. Help me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trick is to use filters on the [FakeXMLHttpRequest](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#FakeXMLHttpRequest) object of the server. Then only the request you filter out will use the fake server:

```
server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
server.xhr.useFilters = true;

server.xhr.addFilter(function(method, url) {
  //whenever the this returns true the request will not faked
  return !url.match(/example.com/);
});

server.respondWith("GET", "http:\\example.com", [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, '{"Body:""asd"}'])
```